# The one that makes the synthesis

Tags: word-request, terminology

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**synthesis**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synthesis)

> the mixing of different ideas, influences, or things to make a whole that is different, or new

Is there any related noun that shares the same root **synth** for the one that "executes" the mix, the agent that creates it. If not, what is the noun that applies to that agent?

Note:
**synthesizer** looked promising but it was a mirage
[No pun intended with the [Ensoniq Mirage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensoniq_Mirage) synthesizer]

**[synthesizer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synthesizer)**

> An electronic musical instrument, typically operated by a keyboard,
>   producing a wide variety of sounds by generating and combining signals
>   of different frequencies

EDITED: After @JavaLatte's answer, let me narrow the context. Let's say that we are talking about computing. If we have a program that calculates D as

> A + B + C = D

or the more generic

> func(A, B, C) = D

What's the name that you will use for the program? DAggregator does not sound good, nor DCalculator. I love DSynthesizer but the word has been "hijacked" as pointed by @JavaLatte.

Comment: does not sound **good**.   **sound** like **seem** or **look** wants an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Synthesizer* does not *have* to mean "something that synthesizes sound".

Synthesis is not really synonymous with addition.  When you synthesize A and B, ideally you get something that is no longer A or B.  In A+B+C=D, all these are numbers and you haven't really "synthesized" anything, just added.

In computing/programming, synthesizing would be a function that takes 2 objects of 2 distinct types and outputs a related or derivative object that's a 3rd separate "combined" type.  C++ inheritance can synthesize object types, for example.

In your example, you're calculating or adding, not really synthesizing.

Comment: I'm talking about a function, I've employed the "+" to simplify, to represent a generic function. I've not found evidence in English on-line dictionaries of your assertion: "Synthesizer does not have to mean "something that synthesizes sound"".

Comment: Most dictionaries won't separately list suffixed versions of nouns unless they are overloaded with an additional meaning.  Doesn't mean original suffixed meaning isn't possible.  E.g. you won't find *synthesizing* in the dictionary (Google for example brings up the root word "synthesize").

Comment: But notice that we have such overloading with "synthesizer" and only one meaning is listed. Well, it's not exactly that we have two different meanings. The specialization [synthesize sound] seems to have "obscure" the general one [synthesize something]. Anyway ... you think that it can be used in my case and that it's semantically correct, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

**synthesizer** would be the correct general term for an agent of synthesis, however it has been hijacked by  electronic music industry.

Generally, one uses a specific term that relates to the kind of thing being synthesized: that might be a chemical factory (for bulk chemicals), a lab (for complex chemicals like pharmaceuticals), a plant (which photosynthesises sugars), an editor (for publications), a cook (for foods), etc.